# Python programs exit with "RuntimeError: unidentifiable C++ exception" in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

On the Linux command line and in Jenkins 1.625, my Python programs run fine.  In Jenkins 2.19 with Pipeline, they exit with the message:

```
RuntimeError: unidentifiable C++ exception
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Jenkins uses `@` as a delimiter in the paths of concurrent jobs.  For example,

```
/space/jenkins/workspace/sdk/wave@2/
```

The solution is to specify a different delimiter character using the argument,

```
-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=.
```

and re-start Jenkins.
The above example changes the `@` in the workspace paths for parallel builds to `.`.

On Linux you can implement this change by adding the following to `/etc/default/jenkins`:

```
# Use "." instead of "@" as the delimiter in concurrent workspace paths
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=."
```

Then re-start Jenkins:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```